# GFI breaker trips randomly upon turning on a wall switch?

Tags: wiring

15 amp GCFI breaker trips randomly upon turning on a 2 switch - wall switch?
It is a bathroom circuit with 2 overhead vanity light fixtures, 2 recessed lights with 2 rotary dial dimmer switches & 2 - 4 gang (regular) outlets & 1 single outlet.
The GCFI breaker test trips successfully. The GCFI breaker may trip multiple times but sometimes reversing which of the 2 vanity light switches to turn on first will resolve the trip problem. And sometimes waiting a short period of time will correct the problem?
I have pulled out the wall outlets to check, tighten & replace 2 of the 5 (double) wall outlets. I also pulled the bigger vanity light off to inspect the direct wiring connections.
I also have tried removing all vanity light bulbs, resetting the GCFI breaker & then turning on the 2 wall switches, then reinstalled all of the lightbulbs.
The GCFI breaker tests fine but it is 25 yrs. old. Could the breaker be weak, causing this random problem.
Should I just replace the GCFI breaker? And I do have another GCFI breaker that is in service that I could possibly swap it with & try that?
It is now happening frequently but in the past it has happened like once every 2-3 months?
I would appreciate all help to find a permanent solution to this reoccurring problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Does your breaker also have an arch fault indicator? Could help others troubleshoot.  I had a breaker trip with the arch fault and it turned out the 3-way switch for the ceiling fan speed was bad. I have to turn off the fan to change speeds or risk tripping the breaker. It was about a month of we watching what was going on in the room before I figured that out. Standard "lifespan" of a breaker is 30-40 years (googled) so you could be close there.

Comment: I did not see a fan mentioned that is usually 1 device that causes problems in bathroom circuits. What type of lamps are in the vanity and the recessed fixtures, if all screw In Edison lamps then the next thing to check is the dimmer controls but once every few months may be tough to track down.

Comment: I don’t believe these GFCI breakers are an arc fault as well. Also the heat/light/fan is on a different circuit & unaffected. I use led light bulbs in the vanity light fixtures. And as mentioned, could it be a recess light rotary dimmer switch causing the problem? Should I swap the possible weak GFCI breaker with another GFCI breaker of the same amp rating to see if the problem continues. I don’t have any other 15 amp GFCI breaker problems.

Comment: I will just rotate the recess light dimmer switches to bright & back to min. to see if one of them was maybe in a bad spot? But you do have to push them inward to click the lights on & off ?  I originally suspected a burnt single outlet as the problem but after it was replaced the problem continued. I then replaced one of the 2 single pole wall switches. I also checked the 2 - 4 gang outlets & connections. One of the vanity light fixtures has a bulb socket that is loose & not powered for some reason. I do need to replace it.

Comment: So maybe I have a couple of possible causes of small leakage to neutral, tripping the GCFI breaker? Just not sure how to find the culprit? Thanks !!

Comment: Are any of the recessed cans over a shower or bathtub by chance?

Comment: 1 recessed light In front of the tub & 1 in front of the shower. But the GFCI breaker trips when it has been 12 to 18 hrs since a shower? And there is some moisture from the shower stall directed toward the recessed light? Could a damp recessed light bulb cause the breaker trip? I’m open to all possibilities! Thanks

Comment: Just thinking, the bathroom gets a fair amount of moisture at times. Enough to fog the vanity mirrors. So it all has been exposed to high moisture conditions for 25 years.  Also, could it be loose GFCI breaker wire connections?

Comment: @kourso -- try disconnecting fixtures from the circuit one at a time and seeing if the GFCI stops tripping

Comment: Yes, I will have to try that, disconnect each fixture, one at a time. If it still trips I would tend to think a weak GFCI breaker or... actually a wiring problem somewhere? Thanks for your great assistance!   I appreciate all of you on this forum!